# How to handle samples with multiple images in a pytorch image processing model?

Tags: pytorch, tensor, mini-batch

My model training involves encoding multiple variants of a same image then summing the produced representation over all variants for the image.

The data loader produces tensor batches of the shape: `[batch_size,num_variants,1,height,width]`.
The `1` corresponds to image color channels.

How can I train my model with minibatches in pytorch?
I am looking for a proper way to forward all the batch_size×num_variant images through the network and summing the results over all groups of variants.

My current solution involves flattening the first two dimensions and doing a for loop to sum the representations, but I feel like there should be a better way an d I am not sure the gradients will remember everything.

Comment: Have you considered 3D Convolution models? They're designed for such approaches. You could consider the no. of variants as `depth` in a 3D Convolution. An input to `nn.Conv3d` is of the form `batch_size*channels*depth*height*width`.

Comment: @planet_pluto I do not think 3D convolutions are what I'm looking for. Operations on images are shared over variants. It is the same model operating on all variants of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understood you correctly, but I guess this is what you want (say the batched image tensor is called `image`):

```py
Nb, Nv, inC, inH, inW = image.shape

# treat each variant as if it's an ordinary image in the batch
image = image.reshape(Nb*Nv, inC, inH, inW)

output = model(image)
_, outC, outH, outW = output.shape[1]

# reshapes the output such that dim==1 indicates variants
output = output.reshape(Nb, Nv, outC, outH, outW)

# summing over the variants and lose the dimension of summation, [Nb, outC, outH, outW]
output = output.sum(dim=1, keepdim=False)
```

I used `inC`, `outC`, `inH`, etc. in case the input and output channels/sizes are different.